# Running Emacs in the same window as command line

Tags: emacs, frame

How to make Emacs to be started by `emacs` in the same window as command line? I can do it by typing `emacs -nw`, but can I put a line into `.emacs` so that it would work automatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

By the time your .emacs is read, the choice whether to use a graphical or non-graphical display has been made.

Perhaps a shell alias would better suit your needs

```
alias emacs 'emacs -nw'
```

You can verify this by adding

```
(y-or-n-p "Sourcing .emacs...")
```

at the top of your .emacs and run both graphical and non-graphical variants of Emacs, either way you get prompted after the Emacs has come up (graphically or non-graphically).

Comment: 'Course I despise aliases, and would use a shell function instead:
emacs ()
{
    command emacs "$@" -nw
}

Answer (score 2):

The other thing to keep in mind is that most Linux distributions have a package which allows for the installation of emacs without graphical support. On Debian-based distros this is emacs-nox. Furthermore, since the development of emacs23 was completed, emacs now has a daemon mode so you can use emacsclient to connect to a single running instance of emacs. This might give you some flexibility if you desire the ability to use both graphical and non-graphical clients.